# Why is opening json files so slow on a Google Cloud VM

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

Good morning ! My goal is to retrieve data from about 1 million small json files contained in a certain path. When I run this code on my personal computer, the computation time to retrieve all these files is smooth, and fast. (10000 json ~ 2 seconds)
I work at the same time on a Google virtual machine (with GPU) and this time is very variable. Sometimes it can take 1 minute for 1000 json and sometimes the program reads 10000 json at once. Moreover I did not have this problem yesterday while running the program. Do you have any idea where it could come from? I also have the impression that the CPUs are underutilized by launching htop. Maybe it comes from there...

My code is the following. Thank you in advance !

```
sentences = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in files:
        if 'json' in name : 
            texts += 1
            with open(root+'/'+name,'r') as f:
                res = json.loads(f.read())
                sentences.append(res['text'])
            logging.info(texts)
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but please note that your method returns false positives.  It will trigger on the file: `djsonic.txt`. I would use `if name.lower().endswith('.json')):` to make sure the filename ends with `.json`, and to make sure case doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you very much you are totally right I change that to avoid this type of error

Comment: What's your VM config (CPU/memory, disk type) and your personal computer spec (CPU/memory, disk type)? When you compare perf, you have to compare comparable things!!

Comment: actually, to expand on what guillaume said, GCE disk performance is dependant on the type and size of said disk. The larger the size, the faster it is. Some types are of course also faster than others. A good starting point for that is [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks). Note that a GPU has absolutely zero impact on disk speeds.